# How to mount the root directory of docker container as a NFS mount point

Tags: docker, mount, nfs

I'm new to docker, and I'm trying mount the root directory of docker container as a NFS mount point.
for example, I had a NFS mount point `test:/home/user/3243`, and I'm trying:

```
docker run -it -v "test:/home/user/3243":/ centos7 /bin/bash
```

absolutely, it's failed. So I tried this:

```
mount -t nfs test:/home/user/3243 /mnt/nfs/3243
docker run -it -v /mnt/nfs/3243:/ centos7 /bin/bash
```

but failed again, so how to do this? Could it be worked out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of issues here:

1. You cannot mount to the root directory of a container. So `docker run -v /foo:/` will never work.
2. With the syntax of your first attempt, `-v test:/foo:bar`, Docker would see this as wanting to create a "named" volume called "test".

You should be able to first do the NFS mount, then do `docker run -v /mnt/nfs/3243:/foo` to have the nfs path mounted to `/foo`.
But again, you can't mount to `/`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! By the way, why cannot mount to the root directory of a container? Is there some documents for this?

Comment: Because this would overwrite the entire container fs.

Comment: Thanks @cpuguy83! I post my original purpose at [How to run docker container on high available storage like NFS,EBS,flock etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227359/how-to-run-docker-container-on-high-available-storage-like-nfs-ebs-flock-etc), want to hear from you if possible~

Answer (score 0):

That is currently discussed (since mid 2014) in [issue 4213](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4213).

One recent workaround by [Jeroen van Bemmel (jbemmel)](https://github.com/jbemmel) was:

> It appears that NFS functionality depends on the underlying storage driver ( aufs, devicemapper, etc. ), as well as the sharing of file handles between processes ( see blog post "[docker: `devicemapper` fix for “device or resource busy” (`EBUSY`)](http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/11/docker-devicemapper-fix-for-device-or-resource-busy-ebusy/)") i.e. 'unshare' may have an impact on NFS mounts.
>
> I've moved away from using the '`MOUNTPOINT=/vm/nfs`' as I am not sure if that event is even emitted.
> Instead I created an `upstart` file like this:

```
cat > /etc/init/ecdn.conf << EOF
description "eCDN container"
author "Jeroen van Bemmel"
# mounted MOUNTPOINT=/vm/nfs doesn't seem to work, at least not the first time
start on started docker and virtual-filesystems
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
respawn
script
exec /usr/bin/docker start -a ecdn
end script

pre-stop script
/usr/bin/docker stop ecdn
# dont /usr/bin/docker rm ecdn
end script

EOF
```

> and then create the container like this:

```
script -c "docker create -it --name='ecdn' --volume /vm:/usr/share/nginx/html/vm:ro image/name"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I had two important point: use NFS and mount on root directory. I read that issue most aboud NFS mount, do you know how to mount on root directory?